# Can NUTCH be used to fetch data from e-commerce sites?

Tags: database, web-scraping, nutch, web-crawler

I want to fetch data from sites.
Example I want prices of different items from ebay.
I want to store those products with their prices in my database.
Will NUTCH be helpful here?
If not then what scraper/crawling i should prefer?

Comment: What are you expecting? If you are expecting a prepackaged solution, then no, if you are expecting to write some code, then yes, it will do the job.

Comment: ok so i have started nutch and it is working.
now for feching data from e-commerce sites i have to write a parser as u suggested.
but so far i havent found any useful tutorial or documentation regarding how to wirte a parser
can u help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Nutch does is crawl some websites and index their webpages.

What you need is a scraper, which is used to extract specific information from some webpages. I don't know what tools are available out there for scraping but it should be pretty easy to write one of your own using some scripting language like Perl or Python.

However if you want to use Nutch for scraping you can build your own plugin to extract additional data. You can find more about plugins on this link: https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/PluginCentral.

You should notice that scraping is not always legal, some sites specifically prohibit any automated download of content from their pages, you should check that site's Term of Use before trying to scrape it.

Answer (score 1):

try scrapy it's a very powerful and well documented scraping framework.
It takes a few hours for experienced programmer to scrap e-commerce data.